# Adding a class to images depending on their orientation in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm building a website with Wordpress and I'm using a child theme I created.

I would like to add a class to all my images depending on their orientation. (.portrait or .landscape)
I did it with javascript but I have no idea how to do it with php.
(I don't know very well yet how to use filters and so)

I have 2 questions:

1 - Is it a good idea to do it with php instead of javascript performance-wise ?
  2 - If the answer to the previous question is yes, then how can I do that? Using php, how can I check all the images and, depending on their orientation, add the corresponding class (.portrait or .landscape) ?

Comment: What WordPress function are you using to insert the images? wp_get_attachment_image()?

Comment: For now I needed it only for featured images so I'm using either the_post_thumbnail() or  get_the_post_thumbnail().
But it could be useful also for other types, so yes wp_get_attachment_image() could be useful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it's better to do it with PHP rather than JavaScript, for user interaction reasons. The back-end performance cost is negligible.
2. You'd use a WordPress filter inside of the [wp_get_attachment_image function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1021) called `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`. This lets you change the class attribute before the image is output.

Here's how the filter would work:

```php
function add_orientation_class( $attr, $attachment ) {

    $metadata = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true);

    // Sanity check: we need both width and height to add the orientation class. If either are missing, we should return the attributes.
    if ( empty($metadata['width']) || empty($metadata['height'])) {
        return $attr;
    }

    // Sanity check x2: class should be set by now, but another filter could have cleared it out.
    if ( !isset($metadata['class'])) {
        $metadata['class'] = '';
    }

    if ( $metadata['width'] > $metadata['height'] ) { // If width is greater than height, the image is a landscape image.
        $attr['class'] .= ' landscape';
    } else { // If not, it's a portrait image.
        $attr['class'] .= ' portrait';
    }

    // Return the attributes.
    return $attr;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'add_orientation_class', 10, 2 );
```